# parent category not showing in list

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue related to query, i have a table for categories, Sub categories are also mentioned the same table with its parent id..

I have wrote an query, its showing all categories and Parent category name, but its not shwoing the Parent Category in the list, can you tell me how this query can be modified that all categories show on the page. either its parent or not..

Below is my query:

```
SELECT P.catName,P.cID,P.catParent,P.catLink,P.catIcon,P.catStatus, U.catName AS 
Parent_name FROM `dev_web_categories` AS P INNER JOIN `dev_web_categories` AS U 
ON U.cID = P.catParent
```

The table is :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of main categories dont have parent categories (because they are on the top), then `INNER JOIN` will not join their parent, so you have to use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

So change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT P.catName,P.cID,P.catParent,P.catLink,P.catIcon,P.catStatus, U.catName AS 
Parent_name FROM `dev_web_categories` AS P LEFT JOIN `dev_web_categories` AS U 
ON U.cID = P.catParent
```